# How to load Widows Global Assembly Cache (GAC) DLLs into .NET Spark spark-submit

Tags: c#, apache-spark

Am working on .NET for Spark (currently .NET Core SDK 3.1) on Windows project, which has been developed on a local dev environment. Spark is working fine, but my customer has need to load Windows GAC DLLs into the spark-submit command when fired from Command prompt.

So is there any way we can pass the GAC directory to spark-submit when we're firing it as a parameter to "dotnet'.
E.g. on my Windows11 laptop dev environment, GAC is stored here > C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64

We're seeing this error:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

Questions:

- Could we pass GAC as parameter to "dotnet" for spark-submit command as parameter in Windows?
- If not, then could upgrading to SDK .NET 5.0 solve this issue?
- If not, then could we opt to use Linux and solve this issue with a softlink (ln) to GAC directory?

Comment: No, .NETCore does not use a GAC.  Simply install the v3.1 version.

Comment: Thanks Hans for the confirmation. Yes, i got this link as well, which says, .NETCore 2.0 used the concept of "runtime package store" but it is not the same as loading DLLs from GAC.